# How do I use gsub to replace “&” (only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, gsub

I have this string "tv&media" and all I want to do is remove the "&" symbol.

Please can you explain how I do this as I've tried but I don't really know what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

What have you actually tried so far?

It's really just

```
"tv&media".gsub('&', '')
# => "tvmedia"
```

Check out the [rubydoc on gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-gsub) for more details.

Note: `.gsub` returns a new string and leaves the original string untouched.  If you want to change the original string, you need `.gsub!`

Comment: Thats what I tried and then realised I was editing the wrong script. DOH! How can I use a single gsub() to remove all white space and special characters from the string? For example: "TV & media's" should be "tvmedias"

Comment: In that case you wanna use a regex as the first parameter to `gsub`.  Something like `gsub(/\W+/, '')` would work in that example to remove all non-word characters.  You'd have to do some research into regular expressions to find something that would work in more complicated cases.